# Tornado facebook_request() to get email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tornado

I'm using tornado and trying to get a facebook user's email address from the Graph API. I have the following code (most of which is from the Tornado website)

```
class FacebookAuth2Handler(BaseHandler,tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
  @tornado.gen.coroutine
  def get(self):
      if self.get_argument("code", False):
          user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=self.settings["facebook_redirect_uri"],
                                                   client_id=self.settings["facebook_app_id"],
                                                   client_secret=self.settings["facebook_secret"],
                                                   code=self.get_argument("code"))
          ob = yield self.facebook_request("/me/email",access_token=user["access_token"])
          print(ob)

      else:
          yield self.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=self.settings["facebook_redirect_uri"],
                                        client_id=self.settings["facebook_app_id"],
                                        extra_params={"scope": ["email","public_profile"]})
```

The problem seems to be fetching the /me/email with the facebook_request() this crashes with the following:

```
tornado.auth.AuthError: Error response HTTP 400: Bad Request fetching https://graph.facebook.com/me/email?access_token=xxxxxxx
```

Comment: It is `/me?fields=email` and not `/me/email`

Comment: Hi WizKid thanks for the response. i tried to change my request func to self.facebook_request("/me?fields=email",access_token=user["access_token"]) but i'm still getting a tornado.auth.AuthError: Error response HTTP 400: Bad Request fetching https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email?access_token=

Comment: Wiz i think you're right something weird is happening when i cut and paste the url into a browser i get the following: {
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "xxx"
   }
}

Comment: I don't get it because I'm using the token straight away that i get

Answer (score 1):

Setting the path to `"/me/email"` is not valid, and setting it to `"/me?fields=email"` causes it to send your url as `"/me?fields=email?access_token=xxxxxxx"`, which is no good either.

use the `fields` parameter:

```python
ob = yield self.facebook_request(
    path="/me",
    access_token=user["access_token"],
    fields="email,gender"
)
```

or you can really simplify things by adding the `extra_fields` parameter to `get_authenticated_user`. Note it is a python `list`, not a comma-separated string like above:

```python
user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=self.settings["facebook_redirect_uri"],
                                         client_id=self.settings["facebook_app_id"],
                                         client_secret=self.settings["facebook_secret"],
                                         code=self.get_argument("code"),
                                         extra_fields=['email','gender']
)
```

Any missing or unpermitted fields will show as `None` in the returned `user` mapping object.

Comment: updating the fields argument in the yield self.facebook_request worked for me